# Networking middleware

Tags: networking

<strike>I'm looking for a networking middleware that may be suitable for a medium-sized MMO.</strike>

I don't care in which language it's written, just that it's high-level, stable and has many of the features that can ease my development. I am making a 2D real-time action game.

Come to think of it... I'd be happy with "just" a high-level networking framework that has a few handy features to ease the development of a general networked game.

Comment: There's not a single question mark in your entire post. Ask something specific.

Comment: What do you work with? Your language limits you to certain products/frameworks. You don't want to use a java networking library, if you work in C# or C++...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check [Zoidcom](http://www.zoidcom.com/) or [Raknet](http://www.jenkinssoftware.com/), I've heard good things about both of them.